# PHP script display as text in browser

Tags: php

I have installed PHP, Apache in my Linux server. http://localhost/index.htm displaying correctly. To test the PHP I have created test PHP file phpinfo.php. Here is the code in that file

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

But when try to http://localhost/phpinfo.php, browser displays script in the file. Apache did not execute the script in the file. What would be reason for this?

Comment: Check `httpd.conf` and see if you've configured it to treat PHP files as `application/x-httpd-php`.

Comment: did you restart apache after you installed and configured php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this means that php is not enabled for your webserver. Have you restarted apache after installing php as well as have you tried `a2enmod php` or `a2enmod php5`

Comment: How about CentOS? There is no `a2enmod` there.

Answer (score 6):

You have not configured Apache to run .php files through PHP.

In the [installation manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) those would be the lines about

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

and

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

You probably want to add `index.php` to the default files as well.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.0, the following should work:

```
apt update
apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

If it does not work, run `a2enmod php7.0` and `service apache2 restart`.

Answer (score -2):

This problem can occur if the <? open short tag is no longer allowed by your php compiler. If PHP short tags are used and the site has been updated or the site is new, be sure to check phpinfo() on the domain and each subdomain that may be in use to see if the use of short tag is permitted. The parameter short_open_tag must be "on".  That was my problem and all the code displayed disappeared with PHP working as expected.

Comment: Did you read the question? They have shown the code. It doesn't use short tags.